# Elastic search - recreating LIKE in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I need to implement a search function in elastic search that will work the same way as MySQL 'LIKE' query.

I have the following code in PHP

```
    public function setUp($reference)
{
    $parameter = DqlPartial::uniqueParameterName('reference');

    $partial = $this->getBaseDqlPartial();
    $partial->where("IFNULL(Asset.supplierReference, '') LIKE :$parameter");
    $partial->setParameter($parameter, '%' . $reference . '%');
    $this->addJoins($partial, $partial->getWhere());
    $this->setDqlPartial($partial);

    if (strpos($reference, "*") !== false) {
        $termQuery = new SimpleQueryString($reference, ["supplierReference"]);
    } else {
        $termQuery = new MatchPhrase();
        $termQuery->setField('supplierReference', $reference);
    }
    $eqPartial = new EqPartial();
    $eqPartial->setQuery($termQuery);
    $this->setEqPartial($eqPartial);

    return $this;
}
```

You can see that if the search string contains '*' in any position I am doing a MatchPhrase function instead of a simple query.

The problem is that MatchPhrase is case sensitive, what parameters I need to pass to this function to make it behave like a simple LIKE query in MySQL, like this:

```
SELECT asset_id, asset_supplier_reference 
FROM assets 
WHERE asset_supplier_reference LIKE 'Opale%'
```

Which returns results like: Opale123, OPALE33, opaletest, opale_ etc.

The only thing I found that is close is [fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness) which I don't like because it is not precise, I need something that will exactly match for the beginning of the string (regardless of the letter case).

P.S I am improving an already existing system, I have no idea why this doesn't work already since I have this line

```
$partial->setParameter($parameter, '%' . $reference . '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending if you want to match the beginning of a word or the beginning of a phrase, you can use a prefix query or a match_phrase_prefix query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix" : { "content.description" : "cur" }
  }

"match_phrase_prefix": {
      "message": {
        "query": "quick brown f"
      }
    }
```

If you can modify your  index mapping you can optimize this with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-prefixes.html

But prefix query are heavy.
You can do better by adding a mapping with a ngram on your field and then a classical match will work.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html

```
GET my-index-00001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "Quick Fo", 
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```